# How to define a thumbnail image to use in browsers like Opera and Safari

Tags: html, safari, opera, favicon

How to set an image to show on Safari's bookmarks and on Opera's Speed Dial? Do I need to set some specific tag or are the browsers using the favicon/logo from the websites?

Here's an example:
[image]

#### EDIT #1

I've added the `<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/images/apple-ico.png" />` and it is working on Safari right now, but on Opera nothing so far...

Comment: Well, did you try the favicon?

Comment: @Roope So, i just tried adding some tags on the `head` for Safari and now its working, but on Opera nothing so far...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the shortcut icon tag?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="[file_name]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Opera

Apparently you cannot control the appearance of your thumbnail image in the Opera Speed Dial as the web site developer.

Opera documents the way [the *user* can control the Speed Dial icons](https://blogs.opera.com/news/2015/07/customize-operas-speed-dial/), but this is up to your visitors. The procedure is not that intuitive: the image cannot be selected from the Speed Dial, but from the "heart" bookmark:

[image]

And the result may not be that great:

[image]

The best you can do is preparing an image dedicated to Opera, with correct ratio. Clearly not the definitive solution anyone would expect.

## iOS Safari

This is done with the [Apple Touch icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html). There are a lot of sizes you should generate in order to support all iOS devices. If you create only one, make it 180x180, opaque (no transparency, else iOS will fill the transparent regions with black) and declare it with:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

Comment: You can zoom in/out and drag the image around to get the perfect placement. If you want a custom image as the thumbnail, replace a picture with a url to your custom image in the page's HTML and the thumbnail chooser should pick it up